# increaseQuantity error - A solution?

Tags: java

I'm stuck on an exercise which is really starting to hold me back in class. Basically in this code, I'd like the result of this deliver method to call the `increaseQuantity` method, and while I believed that it was simple enough I am constantly met with an error when compiling.

The error message reads:

> method increaseQuantity in class Product cannot be given to given types; required int; found:no arguments; reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length.

I've literally hit a wall with this, so any help would be appreciated tenfold!

```
public int delivery (int id, int amount) 
{
    int index = 0;
    boolean searching = true;
    Product myproduct = stock.get(0);
    while(searching && index < myproduct.getID()){
        int Products = myproduct.getID();
        if(Products == id) {
            searching = false;
        }
        else {
            index++;
        }
    }
    if(searching) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return myproduct.increaseQuantity();
    } 
}
```

Many thanks to those who respond.

Comment: Well, you need to add an `int` argument, as stated in the error

Comment: Looks like your `increaseQuantity()` method is expecting an `int` as an argument, but you're giving it nothing. Also, if you're "literally" hitting walls when programming, you need to get in touch with your workplace's health and safety representatives.

Comment: Maybe you could share your Product class code or at least the source for the increaseQuantity() method

Comment: Please post the compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Bit broad and code missing, but if your problem is code does not compile, here you have a working example with explanations inside code.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO do something
    }

    // must fill it somehow
    private List<Product> stock;

    // method signature wants an int as return type!!       
    public int delivery(int id, int amount) {
        int index = 0;
        boolean searching = true;
        Product myproduct = stock.get(0);
        while (searching && index < myproduct.getID()) {
            int Products = myproduct.getID();
            if (Products == id) {
                searching = false;
            } else {
                index++;
            }
        }
        if (searching) {
            // this already returns an int (0)
            return 0;
        } else {
            // your error was here because
            // increaseQuantity does not return an int *
            return myproduct.increaseQuantity();  //   |
        }                                         //   |
                                                  //   |
    }                                             //   |
                                                  //   |  
}                                                 //   |
                                                  //   |
class Product {                                   //   |
    // just my guess                              //   |
    private int ID;                               //   |
                                                  //   |
    public int getID() {                          //   |
        return this.ID;                           //   |
    }                                             //   |
                                                  //   |
    // here must be your problem, now this        //   |
    // method signature says to return an int!!   //   |    
    public int increaseQuantity() {               //   |
        // ↑ this indicates return type!               |
        // *-------------------------------------------*

        // add here your method logic
        return 0; // change this!
    }

}
```